# RolesAllowedDynamicFeature not invoked in Jersey

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jakarta-ee-security-api

My Jakarta Application class is:

```
@ApplicationPath("/app")
@RolesAllowed("admin")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {
    public Application() {
        System.out.println("!!!!!! Insights starts !!!!!....");
        packages("com.company.application.ws");
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
        register(SecurityFilter.class);
        register(AuthenticationExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

My authorization filter is:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class SecurityFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    jakarta.inject.Provider<UriInfo> uriInfo;
//    @Inject
//    private UserService userService;
    private static final String REALM = "My App";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext filterContext) throws IOException {
        User user = authenticate(filterContext);
        filterContext.setSecurityContext(new Authorizer(user));
    }

    private User authenticate(ContainerRequestContext filterContext) {
        // Extract authentication credentials
        String authentication = filterContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (authentication == null) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Authentication credentials are required", REALM);
        }
        if (!authentication.startsWith("Basic ")) {
            return null;
            // additional checks should be done here
            // "Only HTTP Basic authentication is supported"
        }
        authentication = authentication.substring("Basic ".length());
        String[] values = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(authentication), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII).split(":");
        if (values.length < 2) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(400);
            // "Invalid syntax for username and password"
        }
        String username = values[0];
        String password = values[1];
        if ((username == null) || (password == null)) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(400);
            // "Missing username or password"
        }

        // Validate the extracted credentials
        User user;
        if (username.equals("admin") && password.equals("1234")) {
            user = new User("admin", "admin");
            System.out.println("admin AUTHENTICATED");
        } else if (username.equals("user") && password.equals("123")) {
            user = new User("user", "user");
            System.out.println("user AUTHENTICATED");
        } else {
            System.out.println("USER NOT AUTHENTICATED");
            throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid username or password\r\n", REALM);
        }
        return user;
    }

    public class Authorizer implements SecurityContext {

        private final User user;
        private final Principal principal;

        public Authorizer(final User user) {
            this.user = user;
            this.principal = () -> user.username;
        }

        @Override
        public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
            return this.principal;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
            return (role.equals(user.role));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSecure() {
            return "https".equals(uriInfo.get().getRequestUri().getScheme());
        }

        @Override
        public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
            return SecurityContext.BASIC_AUTH;
        }
    }

    public static class User {

        public String username;
        public String role;

        public User(String username, String role) {
            this.username = username;
            this.role = role;
        }
    }
}
```

the issue is that the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` filter is never triggered. I have put the `RolesAllowed` at the Application, class and method level but it never triggers. The `isUserInRole` method is never called. This is a Java only program with no `web.xml`.

What other config is required to make it work?

Update:

I made a local copy of `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` and registered it instead of the Jersey one. The `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.configure` is getting triggered and also the `RolesAllowedRequestFilter(String[] rolesAllowed)` constructor but the `RolesAllowedRequestFilter.filter` and `RolesAllowedRequestFilter.isAuthenticated` are never called.

Comment: This is a feature specific to Jersey. Are you using an EE server that uses Jersey? Are you seeing your logs from the `ResourceConfig` class. Also `@RolesAllowed` is supposed to go on your resource methods or resource classes. Not the `ResourceConfig` class

Comment: @BalusC That is super wierd. Nothing like that is mentioned in the Jersey documentation. [https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/3.1.3/user-guide.html#security]

The `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` filter comes from Jersey. Will this also only work on EJBs?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I am using Tomcat 10.1. I am getting logs from the `ResourceConfig` class. I have put the `@RolesAllowed` annotation in my resource class also but it still has no effect.

Comment: @BalusC The main issue I am facing is that the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` filter is not getting triggered at all.